# how to install node Linux Binaries (.tar.xz) file in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu

I have downlaoded the latest node package installer from their homepage https://nodejs.org/en/ and the latest package from https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.4.0/node-v4.4.0-linux-x64.tar.xz and I am trying to install it in Linux.
There seems to be no instructions in the website so I have decompressed the file and I am using instructions given in README.md file.
It says the following

```
  $ ./configure
  $ make
  $ [sudo] make install
```

From my decompressed folder I am running theses commands,but I am getting an error:

> bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

For kind info: I am having Python 2.7.6, and gcc.

How to install the downloaded file "node-v4.4.0-linux-x64.tar.xz" in my ubuntu system ?

Comment: This is what I use: RUN curl https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.3.1/node-v6.3.1-linux-x64.tar.xz | tar -Jxf - && cp -r node-v6.3.1-linux-x64/{bin,include,lib,share} /usr/ && rm -rf node-v6.3.1-linux-x64

Answer (score 7):

Tarballs that include the OS and CPU architecture in the filename indicate *pre-compiled* binary tarballs. That means there is nothing to compile, so `./configure`, `make`, and `make install` are not of any use there.

Just extract the binary tarball to whatever prefix you want. For example:

`tar Jxf --strip=1 -C /usr/local node-v4.4.0-linux-x64.tar.xz`

Comment: tar Jxf node-v4.4.0-linux-x64.tar.xz  and then sudo cp node-v5.7.0-linux-x64/{bin,include,lib,share} /usr/

Comment: @C0de8ug: Actually the two commands should be: 1. tar Jxf no....tar.tx 2. sudo cp -r node...tar.tx /usr/local/ (You should use the local directory if you do not want to influence other installations as well...)

Comment: Run `wget -O - https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.10.0/node-v6.10.0-linux-x64.tar.xz | tar Jx --strip=1 -C /usr/local` as root.